# How to wait data till it comes by using dependency injection from fire store using Bloc Cubit and Bloc Consumer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get data from FireStore it works fine after I restart the app but it shows this error for a second and brings to me the data, after first register or sign in it shows the below error till I restart the app:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building BlocBuilder<AppCubit, AppStates>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<AppCubit, AppStates>#783ea):
The getter 'cover' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: cover
```

I tried to add a `circular indicator` when the receiver is null like the below code:

```
                          image: userModel.cover == null
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                              : DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                    '${userModel.cover}',
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
```

and this is the below `getUserData` method:

```
  UserModel model;

  void getUserData() {
    emit(AppGetUserLoadingState());
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
      // print(value.data());
      model = UserModel.fromJson(value.data());
      emit(
        AppGetUserSuccessState(),
      );
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      emit(
        AppGetUserErrorState(
          error.toString(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

and this is the below model I have:

```
class UserModel {
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String uId;
  String image;
  String cover;
  String bio;
  bool isEmailVerified;

  UserModel({
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.uId,
    this.image,
    this.cover,
    this.bio,
    this.isEmailVerified,
  });

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    email = json['email'];
    name = json['name'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    uId = json['uId'];
    image = json['image'];
    cover = json['cover'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    isEmailVerified = json['isEmailVerified'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'phone': phone,
      'uId': uId,
      'image': image,
      'cover': cover,
      'bio': bio,
      'isEmailVerified': isEmailVerified,
    };
  }
}
```

but still get the same error..

this is the below full code:

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var userModel = AppCubit.get(context).model;
        // print(userModel.cover);

        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 190.0,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 140.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                          ),
                          image: userModel.cover == null
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                              : DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                    '${userModel.cover}',
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 51.0,
                      backgroundColor:
                          Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        // radius: responsive.height * 0.025,
                        radius: 50.0,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          '${userModel.image}',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              Text(
                '${userModel.name}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
              ),
              Text(
                '${userModel.bio}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '100',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Posts',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '100',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Posts',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '62',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Photos',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '200',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Followers',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '600',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Followings',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Add Photos'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      IconBroken.Edit,
                      size: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling the `getUserData` in the main while app starts:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  Widget widget;

  uId = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'uId');

  if (uId != null) {
    widget = SocialLayout();
  } else {
    widget = LoginScreen();
  }

  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    bool inDebug = false;
    assert(() { inDebug = true; return true; }());
    if (inDebug)
      return ErrorWidget(details.exception);
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        'Error! ${details.exception}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    );
  };

  runApp(MyApp(
    startWidget: widget,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget startWidget;

  MyApp({
    this.startWidget,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()..getUserData()..handleScroll(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: lightTheme,ThemeMode.light,
            themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
            home: startWidget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the state class I have:

```
abstract class AppStates {}

class AppInitialState extends AppStates {}

class AppGetUserLoadingState extends AppStates {}

class AppGetUserSuccessState extends AppStates {}

class AppGetUserErrorState extends AppStates {
  final String error;

  AppGetUserErrorState(this.error);
}

class AppChangeBottomNavBarState extends AppStates {}

class AppChangeBottomSheetState extends AppStates {}

class AppChangeModeState extends AppStates {}

class AppHandleReverseHideBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppHandleForwardHideBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppHideBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppShowBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppNewPostState extends AppStates {}
```

I tried to create a condition in the listener as the below :

```
      listener: (context, state) {
        if(state is AppGetUserErrorState) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (state is AppGetUserSuccessState){
          return AppCubit.get(context).model;
        }
      },
```

After trying debugging I found the `userModel` is with `null` as the below image:

[image]

So After that I make the evaluation with the data is coming `fromJson` and I found every thing is normal as the below image:

[image]

but still not working..

How can I solve this?

Comment: and where is `getUserData` method called?

Comment: @pskink I am calling it when the app starts in the main you can check my updated code :)